# Get copied outlook attachment from clipboard in Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, clipboard, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I am trying to get a copied attachment (through ctrlL+c) from clipboard in outlook 2016. Following code is what I use and is functional for all outlook versions except for 2016. This method is being called when the user simulates a copy through CTRL+C.

```
void GetClipBoardFiles()
{                
            // Getting the outlook process id using windows API
            int outlookProccessId = GetProcessCurrent();
            // getting the clipboard process id using windows API
            IntPtr hwndClipboardOwner = GetClipboardOwner();
            //  getting owners process id of clipboard using windows API
            uint processClipboardOwner = GetProcessFromWindowHandle(hwndClipboardOwner);

            // If clipboard owner and outlook process id is equal, this copy is done within outlook.
            if (outlookProccessId == processClipboardOwner)
            {
                string[] fileNames = null;
               // Check for the available files details in clipboard 
                if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
                {
                   // my custom code.
                }
             }
}
```

Above code works fine in outlook 2003,2007,2010 and 2013 but for Outlook 2016, sometimes this code does not work. Even though the ctrl+C is simulated in outlook, owner's process id of clipboard do not match with outlook process id. Even it matches,  `Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList()` method returns false while i can really paste the content which i copied to some folder or desktop. 
Is it something to do with a new behavior of Outlook 2016 ? are there any accurate ways to get the clipboard contents copied in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this scenario in a freshly installed windows 7. This issue automatically got fixed once installing the updates for windows 7.